# É possível renomear uma pasta com arquivos dentro usando VBA (Outlook)?

Tags: vba

Tenho um processo simples onde um arquivo text chega por e-mail e eu devo salvá-lo em um determinado local dentro de uma pasta cuja o nome é uma data que esta dentro deste arquivo.
Com isto em mente desenvolvi o código abaixo que faz o seguinte processo:

1) Através de uma regra de e-mail o Outlook verifica se o remetente da mensagem é o selecionado e caso sim, executa o código
2) O código salva o anexo em uma pasta chamada "temp"
3) O código lê a segundo linha do arquivo salvo onde esta localizada uma data
4) O Código renomeia esta pasta "temp" para a data lida no arquivo

O problema é que quando o código tenta renomear a pasta ele mostra a mensagem de erro de código 70 (Permissão negada).

É possível renomear uma pasta com arquivos dentro usando VBA (Outlook)?

Código:

```
Public Sub SalvarAnexo(Item)

    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strData As String
    Dim caminhoTemp As String
    Dim caminhoFinal As String
    Dim caminhoFtp As String
    Dim fdr

    'MsgBox "Mensagem Recebida de " & Item.Sender & "!"
    'caminhoTemp = "Z:\MIS\08.Bases\01.big data\01.PF\2015\temp"
    'caminhoFinal = "Z:\MIS\08.Bases\01.big data\01.PF\2015\"
    'caminhoFtp = "ftp://upgrademefiles.bigdatacorp.com.br/Arquivos%20TXT/PF/"
    caminhoTemp = "C:\Users\caio.pirino\Documents\temp"
    caminhoFinal = "C:\Users\caio.pirino\Documents\"
    caminhoFtp = "C:\Users\caio.pirino\Documents\SalvaAuto\temp"

    Call CriaDiretorio(caminhoTemp)

    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Right$(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "TXT" Then
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            FileName = caminhoTemp & "\" & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
            strData = objFile.ReadLine
            strData = objFile.ReadLine
            strData = Left$(strData, 10)
            strData = Replace(strData, "-", "")

            caminhoFinal = caminhoFinal & strData



            'Call CriaDiretorio(caminhoFinal)


            'Call Copy_Folder(caminhoTemp, caminhoFinal)

            'Call CriaDiretorio(caminhoFtp)

            'Call Copy_Folder(caminhoFinal, caminhoFtp)

            'Call RenameFileOrDir(caminhoTemp, caminhoFinal)
            On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
            Set fdr = objFSO.GetFolder(caminhoTemp)
            fdr.Name = strData



            objFile.Close


            MsgBox "Your date is " & strData
        End If
    Next Atmt

PROC_ERR:
  MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description, , "RenameFileOrDir"

End Sub

'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub CriaDiretorio(strCaminho As String)

Dim strComp As String, strPart As String


If Not DiretorioExiste(strCaminho) Then


    DiretorioCriado strCaminho

End If

End Sub

Function DiretorioCriado(ByVal caminho As String) As Boolean

DiretorioCriado = True
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

If DiretorioExiste(caminho) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    FSO.CreateFolder caminho
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A pasta não pode ser criada no caminho: " & caminho & ". Check se o caminho esta correto."
    DiretorioCriado = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function DiretorioExiste(ByVal caminho As String) As Boolean

DiretorioExiste = False
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

If FSO.FileExists(caminho) Then DiretorioExiste = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, o problema é que você está fazendo o seguinte:

1 - Abrindo o arquivo
2 - Lendo o arquivo
3 - Pegando a referência da pasta *temp*
4 - Alterando o nome da pasta
5 - Fechando o arquivo

Como o arquivo está aberto no momento que você está tentando renomear a pasta, ocorre o erro (acontece a mesma coisa no Windows Explorer), para resolver isso feche o arquivo assim que você acabar de lê-lo, utilize essa sequência:

1 - Abrir o arquivo
2 - Ler o arquivo
3 - Fechar o arquivo
4 - Pegar a referência da pasta *temp*
5 - Alterar o nome da pasta

Notei que você está chamando a função `DiretorioExiste` duas vezes (no `CriaDiretorio` e no `DiretorioCriado`), creio que não seja necessário fazer isso. Outro detalhe é que ao invés de usar `FolderExists` dentro da função `DiretorioExiste`, você está usando `FileExists`, que nesse caso é errado, pois você quer saber se a pasta existe e não se o arquivo existe.